# Visual studio code ts single quote formatter

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint

I saved my tslint settings a using single quotes but when I save files VSC doesn't change the double quotes into single quotes even when the option is set in ts formatter. How do I ensure double quotes are corrected to single when auto-formatting the file

[image: vc]